# How to create a homebrew formula for a Mono based application?

Tags: c#, ruby, mono, homebrew

I am trying to create a homebrew formula for mono console applicatoin

This is my formula so far:

```
class Fchan < Formula
  desc "4chan image downloader"
  homepage "https://github.com/gabrielgio/FChan.Downloader"
  url "https://github.com/gabrielgio/FChan.Downloader/releases/download/v0.1.2/fchan0.1.2.tar.gz"
  version "0.1.2"
  sha256 "00f46139b6ba50dbbf178b123ab8f54e225e645eb9aebbb5d22031f8ef3cba3e"

  def install
    system "xbuild", "/p:Configuration=Release", "./FChan.sln"
    system "cd", "./FChan.Downloader/bin/Release/"
    system "mkbundle", "-o", "fchand", "FChan.Downloader.exe", "Newtonsoft.Json.dll", "FChan.Library.dll", "--deps"
  end

  test do
    system "false"
  end
end
```

But every time I do `brew install fchan` I get an error:

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/gabrielgio/FChan.Downloader/releases/download/v0.1.2/fchan0.1.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/fchan-0.1.2.tar.gz
==> Verifying fchan-0.1.2.tar.gz checksum
tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/fchan-0.1.2.tar.gz
==> xbuild /p:Configuration=Release ./FChan.sln
Failed to execute: xbuild
```

Can anyone explain to me how to create a proper homebrew formula for mono applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your formula depends on Mono, you need to [define the formula dependency](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md#specifying-other-formulae-as-dependencies) as such:

```
depends_on "mono"
```